# Hausdorff Dimension Definitions

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

I'm doing a project in fractal dimension (1st year of university), and wanted to cover the Hausdorff Dimension. I have done no measure theory, and don't have enough time to completely learn and understand it. I've seen definitions with both Hausdorff content, and Hausdorff measure, and don't know which is most relevant/which I can have more of a chance of understanding without having to learn all the background information.
Thanks

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gB9n2gHsHN4) gives a very understandable introduction to the topic.

Comment: You might also want to look into [box-counting dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension), which has a slightly more intuitive definition (I think).  For self-similar fractals, the two notions of dimension agree.

Comment: Thanks for the video, I have understood the box-counting dimension, but wanted to link it to the Hausdorff dimension as part of my project! Thanks.

Comment: I also recommend what @Omnomnomnom said about the box-counting dimension (maybe consider both upper and lower). You can also relate either notion of dimension to the [square-cube law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-cube_law) and to scaling issues in general.

Comment: "*but wanted to link it to the Hausdorff dimension as part of my project*" You could begin by constructing sequences of real numbers having various box dimensions, keeping in mind that any sequence has Hausdorff dimension zero (special case of any countable set has Hausdorff dimension zero). Then try to construct a compact and countable set in ${\mathbb R}^{n}$ that has any preassigned box dimension less than or equal to $n.$ (Maybe even try for lower box dimension is $\alpha$ and upper box dimension is $\beta,$ where $0 \leq \alpha \leq \beta \leq n$ is arbitrary and specified in advance.)

Comment: The "measure theory" part of Hausdorff dimension is not so important.  Both Hausdorff dimension and box-counting dimension follow the idea of trying to cover the set (i.e. the fractal) with "nice" shapes (either boxes or circles).  With box-counting dimension, we look for the overall trend whereas with Hausdorff dimension, we look at what happens when the boxes/circles are allowed to be arbitrarily small.

Comment: Thank you ! The ideas seem to make a lot more sense now.